# How many fractional digits are supported in deserialization of JSON number to BigDecimal?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, bigdecimal

I have `BigDecimal` with a large number of fractional digits (i.e. digits to the right of the decimal point). On serialization, I get

```
"value" : 0.01234567890123456789
```

But when deserializing, I get a BigDecimal with a value of:

```
0.012345678901234568
```

So, it looks like deserialization via Jackson rounded to 18 decimal places. How many fractional digits are supported on serialization and deserialization using Jackson? How would I support 20 decimal places? Would I need to serialize as a String via something like:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private BigDecimal value;
```

while still deserializing to a BigDecimal?

Comment: I tried your code (jackson 2.12.2) without the JsonFormat annotation and it works fine, maybe some ObjectMapper configuration can be the cause of this issue ?